# Take average of a list after removing the non-numeric characters

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
A = [1,2,'a',3,4,5,9,8]

total = 0

for i in A:

    List = [x for x in A if isinstance(x, int)]
    for t in List:
        total = total + t           
        avg = total / len(List)
        print(avg)
        break
```

I'm trying to remove a the non numeric characters from the list and tried the above code.
But in the end I'm getting

```
0.14285714285714285
0.2857142857142857
0.42857142857142855
0.5714285714285714
0.7142857142857143
0.8571428571428571
1.0
1.1428571428571428
```

What changes should I make?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code:

- Why are you iterating twice?
- What's the meaning of `i`?
- Why are you computing the average at each step?

Follows a working example:

```py
A = [1,2,'a',3,4,5,9,8]

total = 0
List = [x for x in A if isinstance(x, int)]
for t in List:
    total = total + t           
avg = total / len(List)
print(avg) # 4.571428571428571
```

Comment: I actually wanted to create a function for the same... so used i instead of t. Thanks for the update. :)